# Create Vagrant file via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vagrant

I have these lines which I would like to add to Vagrant file which I would like to create via PowerShell

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.communicator = "winrm"  
config.vm.box = "Win_10_V.box"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]       
    vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0', '--target', :id, '--name', 'SmartCard', '--vendorid', '0x096E', '--productid', '0x0007']
    vb.gui = true
end
end
```

I tried this PowerShell cmdlet but it doesn't work because of multiple " symbols.

```
New-Item "D:\VV\Vagrantfile" -type file -force -value "Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.communicator = "winrm"  
config.vm.box = "W_1.box"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]       
    vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0', '--target', :id, '--name', 'SmartCard', '--vendorid', '0x096E', '--productid', '0x0007']
    vb.gui = true
end
end"
```

Here is error output

```
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '2) do |config|
config.vm.communicator = winrm  
config.vm.box = Win_10_V.box
config.vm.provider virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize [modifyvm, :id, --usb, on]
    vb.customize [modifyvm, :id, --usbehci, on]        
    vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0', '--target', :id, '--name', 'SmartCard', '--vendorid', '0x096E', '--productid', '0x0007']
    vb.gui = true
end
end'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item "D:\VV\Vagrantfile" -type file -force -value "Vagrant.configu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I know that I have positional parameters but I need them in my Vagranfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the double-quote in the value you pass (just before the 2) is terminating the string that you're passing as the value. Re-write is using a [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx):

```
$value = @"
"Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.communicator = "winrm"  
config.vm.box = "W_1.box"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]       
    vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0', '--target', :id, '--name', 'SmartCard', '--vendorid', '0x096E', '--productid', '0x0007']
    vb.gui = true
end
end
"@

New-Item "D:\VV\Vagrantfile" -type file -force -value $value
```

This will allow you to have embedded quotes within the string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything works as expected.